# VkKeyScanEx not working on "F" keys and others

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14

Right now I'm grabbing the string of an entry from a QKeySequence object and converting it into a keycode.

Problem is that it doesn't work anything that has more than 1 character, (f1-12/delete/end/etc.).

```
    QString keys = uiPtr->keySequenceEdit1->keySequence().toString();
    const wchar_t keyPtr = *qUtf16Printable(keys);
    short keyVal = VkKeyScanEx(keyPtr, GetKeyboardLayout(0));
    VK = LOBYTE(keyVal);
```

How can I get it to work on keys that have more than 1 char in them?

Answer (score 0):

qUtf16Printable returns:"Returns str as a const ushort *, but cast to a const wchar_t * to avoid warnings"

But in your code you are not assigning the return value to a pointer, the return value is assigned to a character (const wchar_t).

probably try

```
const wchar_t* keyPtr = .........
```

That could be the problem